# Generic way to identify field in table

Tags: php, jquery, database

I am writing a sql editor (sqlite3).

I can display a table and allow users to edit any value in the table but I now need some way of identifying the value editted. The problem is that I don't know what the primary key is and I don't think it's that good an idea to say "update table set a=b where x=123 and y=123 and z=123 and..." for all the fields that aren't "a".

I'm using jquery (and ajax) and php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what the primary key is *(or you don't know if there is an `UNIQUE` index)*, you won't have much of a choice : even if using all fields in your `where` clause, you might update more than one line *(the one the user wanted to edit)*.

You really need some way to identify one precise line -- and that way is the primary key.

Maybe, just out of curiosity, you my check how phpMyAdmin does that ? 

*(I know it's not SQLIte, my MySQL -- but maybe the general idea could be re-used ?)*

Comment: I'm writing something similar to phpMyAdmin - I hadn't thought of checking their code though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could force the user to specify a primary key (or at least a UNIQUE) and then retrieve it with `SHOW INDEX FROM table` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html)

Comment: show index from <table> is what I was looking for, thanks but now to get it for sqlite3?

Comment: The SQL request is the same in sqlite I think. So you can get the primary key with `SHOW INDEX FROM table WHERE key_name = "PRIMARY"`, in the "Column_name" field.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it appears that "select sql from sqlite_master where name='tablename';" is as close as it gets which only returns the sql statement that can be used to generate the table...

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot determine PK or UK column then you have to use "where x=123 and y=123 and z=123", but remember to add LIMIT 1 - then you are sure you don't edit more than one record.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not such a good idea to issue that update '... for all the fields that aren't a'.  You should include a too, along with the old value of a in the row that was edited.